# regex to extract names and values of attributes

Tags: php, regex

I have the following possible strings that I need to turn into arrays so I can feed them into an html generator.  I am not staring with html or XML, I am trying to create a shorthand that will allow me to populate my html objects much simpler and faster with more readable code.

```
id='moo'
id = "foo" type= doo    value ='do\"o'
on_click='monkeys("bobo")'
```

I need to pull out the attribs and their corresponding values.  These attrib strings are not associated with an html or xml tag.  And I would like to do it with 1 to 3 **regular expressions**

- The value may be encapsulated by either single or double quotes
- If the value is encapsulated by quotes it may also contain whitespace, quotes different from encapsulating quotes or escaped quotes that are same as the encapsulating quotes.
- There may or may not be whitespaces between the attrib and =, and the = and value.

The eventual results should look like:

```
array(1) {
  [id] => moo
}
array(3) {
  [id] => foo
  [type] => doo
  [value] => do"o
}
array(1) {
  [on_click] => monkeys("bobo")
}
```

but if it turns out like:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => id
  [1] => moo
}
array(6) {
  [0] => id
  [1] => moo
  [2] => class
  [3] => foo
  [4] => value
  [5] => do"o
}

array(2) {
  [0] => on_click
  [1] => monkeys("bobo")
}
```

I can re-arrange it from there.

Some previous regexes I have tried to use and their issues:

- `/[\s]+/` - Return attrib/value pairs only if there was no whitespace around the =
- `/(?<==)(\".*\"|'.*'|.*)$/` - Returns value including the encapsulating quotes.  It does ignore escaped quotes within the value though
- `/^[^=]*/` - Returns the attribute just fine. regardless of whitespace between attrib and =

Comment: thanks to #regex for getting me at least this far!

Comment: We need a stack exchange site dedicated to regex questions. Seriously.

Comment: @web: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2203/regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any particular reason you want to use regex specifically here?  Seems like a token-based parser might work better for you, as you need to keep more state than is comfortable to do in a regex.

Comment: any suggestions on how I should be going about this?

Comment: State machine, parsing "tokens", and knowing what to expect.  Starts with looking for an identifier, then (skipping spaces), an '='.  Then one of ', " and word token, followed by the same quote, OR just a word token without quotes.  Repeat as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Tyson,

It appears that you have already done some parsing to remove the XML/HTML elements, and are now trying to process the remaining attributes.  In general, regular expressions are not sufficient for parsing XML/HTML.

If you have access to the XML/HTML, you should consider using a DOM processing library / extension to PHP to read in the XML/HTML, and iterate/parse the elements and attributes.

Here is an example reference:

- "Reading and writing the XML DOM with PHP"  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-xmldomphp/

Comment: Unfortunately no, I am putting a framework over the DOM to facilitate faster generation of xml content.  I am familer with the dom and I am trying to make a tool that will parse out an attribute string into an array so I can feed it into my dom objects.